# Bash - save command line paramaters into outfile

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I've got a script which creates random command line parameters for second script. I then save the output the second into a file. How do i include the command line parameters used in the second script along with the output it produces ? The command below saves only the output :

```
./ascpsc -l1=20901 -l2=22134 -l3=fvs1S -l4=221114 >output.log 2>&1
```

Result is a long number, eg. 12993943999193949399

How do i append, on top of the file, complete command line used ?

Answer (score 1):

You can first save the command line and then **append** the output.

```
echo "./ascpsc -l1=20901 -l2=22134 -l3=fvs1S -l4=221114" >output.log
./ascpsc -l1=20901 -l2=22134 -l3=fvs1S -l4=221114 >>output.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for that:

```
log() {
    echo "$*" >> output.log
    "$@" >> output.log 2>&1
}

log ./ascpsc -l1=20901 -l2=22134 -l3=fvs1S -l4=221114
```

`"$*"` create a single string of all arguments to `log` while `"$@"` creates one correctly quoted string per argument of `log` (i.e. `log cmd "a b" c` would call `cmd` with *two* arguments instead of three).

Alternatively, you can play with `set -x` and `exec` to redirect stdout but I can never remember the exact syntax, so the solution above is Better(TM).

Answer (score 0):

If you had your script **generator.sh** that "echo" something, you can do:

```
./generator.sh | cat - output.log > temp && mv temp output.log
```

This prepend output of generator in file output.log

This could be expensive if yor file is quite large.. so you can also use **sed** command.